# Macbook how to access localhost

Tags: macos, tomcat, networking, web-applications

I am trying to set up my working environment at home. I am using a macbook, I did all the set up just like the PC in my office. I am be able to build the projects, start tomcat with no error. But I don't know how to access the running application. I am using VPN to connect the tomcat database in my office, everything looks fine. The problem is, on the PC in my office, I set the 127.0.0.1 point to localhost in the system host file, then I can use localhost/admin to access the application after I started tomcat. I did the same on my mac, and it is not working. Then I found the local ip address should not be the 127.0.0.1 for mac, I searched on the internet to see how to find the ip address, I found my ip address is 192.168.1.191. I use 192.168.1.191/admin, I still didn't see my application. Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: No, it's still 127.0.0.1. That's universal.

Comment: Do you know is there any possible reason that it is not working? Thank you.

Comment: ifconfig lo0 should indicate that 127.0.0.1 is its inet address. From there it's a question of whether you've got your firewall enabled in your Security & Privacy System Preferences and if this copy of Tomcat is somehow set up differently than the other.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check all these when I got home.